# change.delegate is very slow

Tags: aurelia

I have an object wich has two arrays of objects, like this:

```
Interests = {
   MostInterests: [],
   DistinctInterests: []
};
```

I also have an input that when is changed, uses a function to search elements in the Interests.DistinctInterests, but It looks like the change.delegate="function()" is taking a long time to trigger.

```
<input ref="textsearch" change.delegate="searchInterest($event.target.value)" type="text" />

searchInterest(value){
         console.log('SEARCH');
         this.searchedInterests = [];
         var i = 0, j = 0;;
         var upperValue = value.toUpperCase();
         for(i = 0 ; i < this.Interests.DistinctInterests.length ; i++){
             if(this.Interests.DistinctInterests[i].normalizedName.indexOf(upperValue) !=-1){
                 this.searchedInterests[j] = this.Interests.DistinctInterests[i];
                 j++;
             }
         }
         console.log('END SEARCH');
     }
```

The goal is update the view with the elements in `this.searchedInterests`, which contains items that match the searched text.

I don't know if It is an Aurelia problem or a javascript performance. I have aldo tried with $.each() function.

**PS: the list contains 50 elements.**

Comment: Using `input.delegate`?

Comment: Is the `console.log` taking too long to show?

Comment: @nicovank, you have solved my problem, thank you. I didn't know `input.delegate`. It works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `change` event is only fired [when a change to the element's value is committed by the user](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change).

> Think of *commited* as `CTRL+Z` steps

---

This is the reason your function took more time to execute: it just wasn't called.

Instead, by using the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event, your function will get called every time the value changes.

```xml
<input ref="textsearch" input.delegate="searchInterest($event.target.value)" type="text" />
```